# 'float/str/int' object is not callable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

This is my current rough code:

```
class Bank:
    def __init__(self, name, account_number, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.account_number = account_number
        self.balance = balance
        self.transactions = 0
    def balance(self):
        if self.balance >= 0:
            print("Your balance is $" + str(round(self.balance, 2)) + ".")
        elif self.balance < 0:
            print("Your balance is -$" + str(round(self.balance, 2)) + ".")
    def deposit(self, amount):
        if amount >= 0:
            self.balance = self.balance + amount
            if self.balance >= 0:
                print("You deposited $" + str(round(amount, 2)) + " into your account, your balance is now $" +
                      str(round(self.balance, 2)) + ".")
            elif self.balance < 0:
                print("You deposited $" + str(round(amount, 2)) + " into your account, your balance is now -$" +
                      str(round(self.balance, 2)) + ".")
            self.transactions += 1
        else:
            print("Transaction failed, you cannot deposit a negative amount of money.")
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount >= 0:
            self.balance = self.balance - amount
            if self.balance >= 0:
                print("You withdrew $" + str(round(amount, 2)) + " out of your account, your balance is now $" +
                      str(round(self.balance, 2)) + ".")
            elif self.balance < 0:
                print("You withdrew $" + str(round(amount, 2)) + " out of your account, your balance is now -$" +
                      str(round(self.balance, 2)) + ".")
            self.transactions += 1
        else:
            print("Transaction failed, you cannot withdraw a negative amount of money.")
    def summary(self):
        if self.balance >= 0:
            print("Hi " + self.name + " with account# " + str(self.account_number) + ", you have made " +
                  str(self.transactions) + " transactions and your current balance is now $" +
                  str(round(self.balance, 2)) + ".")
        elif self.balance < 0:
            print("Hi " + self.name + " with account# " + str(self.account_number) + ", you have made " +
                  str(self.transactions) + " transactions and your current balance is now -$" +
                  str(round(self.balance, 2)) + ".")

name1 = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
account_number1 = int(input("Please enter " + name1 + "'s account#: "))
balance1 = float(input("Please enter " + name1 + "'s account balance: "))

name2 = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
account_number2 = int(input("Please enter " + name2 + "'s account#: "))
balance2 = float(input("Please enter " + name2 + "'s account balance: "))

name3 = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
account_number3 = int(input("Please enter " + name3 + "'s account#: "))
balance3 = float(input("Please enter " + name3 + "'s account balance: "))

object1 = Bank(name1, account_number1, balance1)
object2 = Bank(name2, account_number2, balance2)
object3 = Bank(name3, account_number3, balance3)

end = False
while end == False:
x = int(input("Enter 1 to use " + name1 + "'s bank account, enter 2 to use " +
              name2 + "'s bank account, enter 3 to use " + name3 + "'s bank account, or enter 4"
                                                                   "to end all transactions (quit): "))
if x == 1:
    a = int(input("Enter 1 to show " + name1 + "'s account balance, enter 2 to deposit money into " +
                  name1 + "'s account, enter 3 to withdraw money from " + name1 +
                  "'s account, or enter 4 to go back and choose another bank account: "))
    if a == 1:
        object1.balance()
    elif a == 2:
        amount = float(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to deposit: "))
        object1.deposit(amount)
    elif a == 3:
        amount = float(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to withdraw: "))
        object1.withdraw(amount)
    elif a == 4:
        continue
    else:
        print("Invalid number, restarting.")
        continue
if x == 2:
    a = int(input("Enter 1 to show " + name2 + "'s account balance, enter 2 to deposit money into " +
                  name2 + "'s account, enter 3 to withdraw money from " + name2 +
                  "'s account, or enter 4 to go back and choose another bank account: "))
    if a == 1:
        object2.balance()
    elif a == 2:
        amount = float(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to deposit: "))
        object2.deposit(amount)
    elif a == 3:
        amount = float(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to withdraw: "))
        object2.withdraw(amount)
    elif a == 4:
        continue
    else:
        print("Invalid number, restarting.")
        continue
if x == 3:
    a = int(input("Enter 1 to show " + name3 + "'s account balance, enter 2 to deposit money into " +
                  name3 + "'s account, enter 3 to withdraw money from " + name3 +
                  "'s account, or enter 4 to go back and choose another bank account: "))
    if a == 1:
        object3.balance()
    elif a == 2:
        amount = float(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to deposit: "))
        object3.deposit(amount)
    elif a == 3:
        amount = float(input("Please enter the amount of money you wish to withdraw: "))
        object3.withdraw(amount)
    elif a == 4:
        continue
    else:
        print("Invalid number, restarting.")
        continue
if x == 4:
    object1.summary()
    object2.summary()
    object3.summary()
    end = True
```

For some reason I keep getting this error when I try to use the balance function in my class:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Larger Class Assignment.py", line 72, in <module>

   object1.balance()

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

This is exactly what I enter into my code:

- Please enter your name: Errin
- Please enter Errin's account#: 234623465
- Please enter Errin's account balance: 500
- Please enter your name: asfdgafd
- Please enter asfdgafd's account#: 6256
- Please enter asfdgafd's account balance: 4362
- Please enter your name: gsfgh
- Please enter gsfgh's account#: 3546
- Please enter gsfgh's account balance: 3456
- Enter 1 to use Errin's bank account, enter 2 to use asfdgafd's bank
  account, enter 3 to use gsfgh's bank account, or enter 4to end all
  transactions (quit): 1
- Enter 1 to show Errin's account balance, enter 2 to deposit money
  into Errin's account, enter 3 to withdraw money from Errin's account,
  or enter 4 to go back and choose another bank account: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `self.balance` twice in your class.

First as **class property** (value, float) with the number of the balance (`self.balance = balance`), second as **class method** (function) to print your current balance (`def balance(self):` which will be called as `self.balance()`).

This crashes in line 72 (with the error above), when your code mixes up the class method and the class property by calling it.

**Solution** Use different property and class names to solve this problem, e.g. `def get_balance(self):` for the method.